# detekt snake case package

Tags: kotlin, detekt

I added [detekt](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt) to my app and it is complaining about my package names conventions.

I use the package snake_cased and the class CamelCased.

For example:

```
package com.my_package

class MyClass
```

And the output from detekt is the following:

```
NamingConventionViolation - [MyClass.kt] at com/my_package/MyClass.kt:1:1
```

I have the following as my naming conventions configuration:

```
NamingConventionViolation:
    active: true
    variablePattern: '^(_)?[a-z$][a-zA-Z$0-9]*$'
    constantPattern: '^([A-Z_]*|serialVersionUID)$'
    methodPattern: '^[a-z$][a-zA-Z$0-9]*$'
    classPattern: '[A-Za-z$][a-zA-Z_.$]*'
    enumEntryPattern: '^[A-Z$][a-zA-Z_$]*$'
```

I changed the default class Pattern to add the possibility to start with lower case and have _ in the class name because I understood that detekt is validating the FQN and not only the name.

So, my question is: how can I set the pattern that detekt uses for package names?

Comment: Hi, this seems pretty cool. Where do you define such patterns? (I want that too :) ). Is that some code-style plugin?

Comment: @guenhter yes, this a gradle plugin for statis analysis: https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your own pattern for package names with the `packagePattern` parameter on the `NamingConventionViolation` rule.

e.g.:

```
NamingConventionViolation:
    active: true
    variablePattern: '^(_)?[a-z$][a-zA-Z$0-9]*$'
    constantPattern: '^([A-Z_]*|serialVersionUID)$'
    methodPattern: '^[a-z$][a-zA-Z$0-9]*$'
    classPattern: '[A-Za-z$][a-zA-Z_.$]*'
    enumEntryPattern: '^[A-Z$][a-zA-Z_$]*$'
    packagePattern: '[a-zA-Z_$]*'
```

Comment: You just missed the dot from the package names. The updated regex is the following: packagePattern: '[a-zA-Z_$]*'